# Docker jar not found

Tags: java, docker

My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:9
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT [“java”,”-jar”,”/app.jar”]
```

When I run `docker build -t myjar` it builds fine.

When I run `docker run image` I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [“java”,”-jar”,”/app.jar”]: not found
```

I heard this could be a "relative path" issue? I'm not sure how to fix it or where the jar should even reside. I need help debugging this.

Comment: I removed the ENTRYPOINT line and it ran fine. So I know the issue is there.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you `ADD` your jar at the root using:

```
ADD target/myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar
```

Additionally, if you don't override the command when you start your image, use `CMD` ([documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)) instead of `ENTRYPOINT` (and also try to use more "normal" quotes instead of `”`):

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

**EDIT:**

Are you sure you're using double quotes ?

**EDIT 2:**

Try without brackets:

```
CMD java -jar /app.jar
```

Comment: Same error:Step 4/4 : RUN [“java”,”-jar”,”/app.jar”]
 ---> Running in ...
/bin/sh: 1: [“java”,”-jar”,”/app.jar”]: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c [“java”,”-jar”,”/app.jar”]' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: Sorry I wrote `RUN` instead of `CMD` in my answer :(. I edited it!

Comment: You were right about the quotes!! that was it. thank you for your help :)

Comment: I'm glad I helped

Comment: Hi If  windows machine is there then go with                                                                                          
      CMD java -jar /app.jar

Answer (score 2):

This Error occurs only in Windows 10 . Use below command

$> docker container commit --change='CMD java -jar /tmp/app-name.jar' <container_name> <docker_registry>/app-name:

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly in windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Please do remember, docker container internal is a Linux (or similar kind of) environment. While we are running the below command on windows command prompt(C:/>) it is missing bash shell

docker container commit --change='CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar"]' boring_archimedes advanceinfo/hello-world-rest-api:manual2

So, we are getting below error

/bin/sh: [java,-jar,/tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar]: not found

Please use one command prompt in windows which support bash shell example Git Bash prompt($)
Note: don't change the above command, only change the command prompt, it will work 1000%

Comment: getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `ADD` instruction to an absolute path:

```
ADD target/myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have solved this using the following command:

```
CMD exec java -jar "$FINALNAME"
```

More detail [here](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/94)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting below error :
docker : /bin/sh: [java,-jar,/tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar]: not found
Below commit resolved my issue in windows 10 :
docker container commit **--change='CMD java -jar /tmp/hello-world-rest-
api.jar'** kind_hermann in28min/hello-world-rest-api:singraul-3
For Linux machine :
docker container commit **--change='CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/hello-world-rest-
api.jar"]'** kind_hermann in28min/hello-world-rest-api:singraul-2

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Paul Rey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49383081/10907864). I experienced a similar issue when trying to deploy a Java application:

This was my `Dockerfile`:

FROM openjdk:8-jre

```
VOLUME /tmp
WORKDIR /app
COPY payment-collection.jks .
RUN cat /app/payment.jks
RUN keytool -list -v -keystore /app/payment.jks -storepass my-name.
RUN mkdir cert
COPY payment.jks /app/cert
COPY  /target/payment-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app
ENTRYPOINT [\"java\",\"-jar\",\"/app/${prod_jar_name}.jar\"]
EXPOSE 443
```

But when I deploy the docker app, I get the error:

> /bin/sh: 1: ["java","-jar","/app/payment-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]: not found

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I simply changed from this:

```
ENTRYPOINT [\"java\",\"-jar\",\"/app/payment-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\"]
```

To this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/payment-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

So my new `Dockerfile` looked like this after then:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

VOLUME /tmp
WORKDIR /app
COPY payment-collection.jks .
RUN cat /app/payment.jks
RUN keytool -list -v -keystore /app/payment.jks -storepass my-name.
RUN mkdir cert
COPY payment.jks /app/cert
COPY  /target/payment-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/payment-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
EXPOSE 443
```